# C: Pipe and Fork closing. Nothing gets printed

Tags: c, linux, pipe

`cmds` is a list of commands to call. In my case, I'm tring to call `ls | grep c`. When I run the program, nothing gets printed. It seems `grep` is waiting for something?

Note: If I only use `ls` (via `execPipe(cmds,1)`), everything works.

What is wrong?

```
int execPipe(char*** cmds,int len){
    int i;
    int pipefd[100][2];
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        pipe(pipefd[i]);
    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (fork() == 0){
            printf("executing #%d %s\n",i,cmds[i][0]);  
            //i=0:  in=sdtin, out=1
            //i=1:  in=1,out=3
            //i=2:  in=3,out=5
            //i=len in=len*2-1, out=sdtout

            close(pipefd[i][0]);

            if(i != 0){
                dup2(pipefd[i-1][1],0); //read becomes the write of last one
            }
            if(i != len-1){
                dup2(pipefd[i][1],1);   //write becomes pipefd[i][1]
            }

            execvp(cmds[i][0],cmds[i]);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        } 
        close(pipefd[i][0]);
        close(pipefd[i][1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){

    char*** cmds = malloc(2*sizeof(char**));
    cmds[0] = malloc(2*sizeof(char**));
    cmds[0][0] = "ls";
    cmds[0][1] = NULL;

    cmds[1] = malloc(3*sizeof(char**));
    cmds[1][0] = "grep";
    cmds[1][1] = "c";
    cmds[1][2] = NULL;

    execPipe(cmds,2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't closed enough pipes in the child process, so `grep` doesn't know it has reached EOF (because it could still write to the pipe that it is reading from, but it won't write to the pipe or close it, so it is stuck waiting for an EOF that won't appear).  Make sure you've thought through which pipe descriptors need to be closed where.  As a rule of thumb, if you duplicate a pipe descriptor to either standard input or standard output, you need to close _both_ of the descriptors from the pipe — and maybe some other pipes too.

Comment: Well, once I'm done calling `execvp` I can close the pipe. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No; once you've called `execvp()`, it is too late. `execvp()` only returns if it fails to execute the program. You don't even need to test its return value; the mere fact that it returns guarantees that it failed. If it succeeds, a new program is running in place of the old one, and doesn't know which file descriptors the old program had open, and won't close them. The child process needs to do close them before calling `execvp()`. The main program also needs to close its copies of the pipes.  You also need to start all the programs in the pipeline before you start waiting for any of them.

Comment: Note, too, that when you have two processes in a pipeline, you need just one pipe; in general, for an N process pipeline, you need N-1 pipes (for N>=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static
int execPipe(char ***cmds, int len)
{
    int i;
    int pids[len];
    int pipefd[len][2];

    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        pipe(pipefd[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int pid;
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            printf("PID %d: executing #%d %s\n", (int)getpid(), i, cmds[i][0]);
            if (i != 0)
            {
                dup2(pipefd[i - 1][0], 0); // JL: Fix
            }
            if (i != len - 1)
            {
                dup2(pipefd[i][1], 1);   // write becomes pipefd[i][1]
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++)    // JL: Fix
            {
                close(pipefd[j][0]);
                close(pipefd[j][1]);
            }
            execvp(cmds[i][0], cmds[i]);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute command %s\n", cmds[i][0]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        else if (pid < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork for %s\n", cmds[i][0]);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            pids[i] = pid;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)       // JL: Fix
    {
        close(pipefd[i][0]);
        close(pipefd[i][1]);
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    int kids = len;
    while (kids > 0 && (corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        printf("PID %d died with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
        for (i = 0; i < kids; i++)
        {
            if (pids[i] == corpse)
            {
                pids[i] = pids[kids-1];
                kids--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char ***cmds = malloc(2 * sizeof(char **));
    cmds[0] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char **));
    cmds[0][0] = "ls";
    cmds[0][1] = NULL;

    cmds[1] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char **));
    cmds[1][0] = "grep";
    cmds[1][1] = "c";
    cmds[1][2] = NULL;

    execPipe(cmds, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comments:

- Notice how many close operations there are.
- It would be reasonable to factor the close loop into a function that gets called where needed.
- You could get away without the first child closing the pipes, but it is silly to break the symmetry.
- It is crucial that the parent close the pipes — but only after the pipes are finished with (that is, after all the children are created).
- The `wait()` loop deals with the situation where the parent process had children that it didn't know about that terminate before the children it launches — a rather unusual but far from impossible circumstance.  It would be possible simply to wait until all children die, but maybe one of the previously created children isn't going to terminate.  The loop waits until all the known children have died and then exits.
- A more complex mechanism would only have two pipes open at any one time, even in a 50 process pipeline, rather than opening all 49 pipes at once, but that's a refinement for later.

You should extend this to a 3-process or longer pipeline and check that it works.  Possible pipelines include:

```
 who | awk '{print $1}' | sort
 who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c
 who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Beware: the shell removes single quotes.